# How do I exclude certain commits from GitHub's stat tracking

Tags: github

Is there any way to exclude certain commits from GitHub's stat tracking?

I occasionally need to commit a 3rd party library. As these tend to be large, they mess up the contributors data (I have 350K additions today, I'm on a roll) and code frequency charts, which is a flat line with a spike every time I check in a library.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only chance will be that you put the dependency in a separate repo (if they do not already have a git repo for it) and add it as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

This way updating to a new version will be only one commit where you update the sha1 of the submodule HEAD you are using.